# How can i send authentication tokens in android for api

Tags: android, authentication

I want to be able to add authentication token every request and do it in a general way.

How to best achieve this in android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor if you are using Spring for android or just

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor.html

Then add the interceptor to your requests using a general singleton class for processing requests.

```
            ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptor = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
        interceptor.add(new LoginInterceptor(getApplicationContext()));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptor);
```

This interceptor should add the auth token if available:

```
    @Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
        ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

    String appAuthToken = settings.getString(
            AUTH_TOKEN.toString(), "");
    // response

    request.getHeaders().add("auth-token", appAuthToken);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}
```

Thats it server side you can check this.

Comment: on a side note You also need to check the tokens in call to 
loadUrl(Strring url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders)